# NodeMCU and HX711 using ESPlorer

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esplorer

I don't know if his is the correct topic to ask this but here it goes:

I have a NodeMCU devkit 0.9 and I'm am able to use ESPlorer to upload basic code like the web server with some buttons that turn on and off LEDs on the board.

I was trying to interface NodeMCU with a load cell amplifier (HX711), which I saw has [libraries for NodeMCU](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/hx711/). How can I "include" `hx711.c` in my .lua file for it to recognize the functions inside `hx711.c`?

The error that appears when I try to send to ESP is

> LUA interpreter error detected
>   stdin:1: attempt to index global 'hx711' (a nil value)..."

Best regards.

Comment: have you compiled the nodemcu firmeware with this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [build a NodeMCU firmware](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/) that includes the [HX711 module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/hx711/). Then you need to [flash](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/flash/) the new firmware to your devkit.